# RE: Installing favicon with serve-favicon : where's the favicon.ico file?

Tags: node.js, npm, favicon

I installed favicon using "npm install serve-favicon".  The subsequent requirement statements all show something like

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/favicon.ico'));
```

...but a favicon.ico file was not installed as part of the npm install . What's up with that?  Is favicon.ico just a dummy text file that I should make? Or should it have been automatically installed with everything else?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply your own icon. That is basically any image, encoded into the .ico format.

[Here is a simple site](http://favicon-generator.org/) that lets you upload a regular image and get the corresponding .ico verison back.